# Formatting C# String

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I would like to print out information about products to the console line, and the code I have that does it is this:

```
const string format = "[PRODUCT_ID] {0, -10} | [SIZE] {1, -10} | [PRICE] {2, -10}"
foreach (DataRow row in productTable.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, row["PRODUCT_ID"], row["SIZE"], row["PRICE"]));
}
```

Ideally, I would like all the " | " to be lined up for the expected output to be:

```
[PRODUCT_ID] 25439  | [SIZE] XS | [PRICE] 34.55 USD

[PRODUCT_ID] 25438  | [SIZE] XL | [PRICE] 27.99 USD

[PRODUCT_ID] 142367 | [SIZE] S  | [PRICE] 27.99 USD

[PRODUCT_ID] 352344 | [SIZE] M  | [PRICE] 12.50 USD
```

But, in reality, the actual output in the console looks like:

```
[PRODUCT_ID] 25439 | [SIZE] XS | [PRICE] 34.55 USD

[PRODUCT_ID] 25438 | [SIZE] XL | [PRICE] 27.99 USD

[PRODUCT_ID] 142367 | [SIZE] S | [PRICE] 27.99 USD

[PRODUCT_ID] 352344 | [SIZE] M | [PRICE] 12.50 USD
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you pasted is actually what's giving you that output? Alignment looks fine to me: [see here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vqM8wP)

Comment: @IvanKhorin Specifying alignment inside string format is totally valid though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0#control-alignment Do you know what the root cause of author's issue might be?

Comment: The issue is almost definitely that the console is not using a fixed width font which means just padding with spaces isn't going to make things line up.  Did you copy and paste the actual results or did you just make fake ones that "look" like the results you got?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, for the second try I've got expected result. As shown in the question, both results are wrong, so maybe there is a problem in casting to string on tables. Because my test code worked fine with lists of ints and strings. Maybe it is a good idea to explicitly use `.ToString()` like `row["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString()`.

Comment: Testing in LINQPad gets a correct result?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance and [edit] the question to inline all the data that produces the alleged bad output.

Comment: format specifiers for strings don't work with integers/decimals...you have to convert the data to a string for it to work

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Incorrect: translating from `DataRow` formats just fine regardless of column type.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
const string format = "[PRODUCT_ID] {0} | [SIZE] {1} | [PRICE] {2}";
foreach (DataRow row in productTable.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, 
        row["PRODUCT_ID"].PadRight(10, ' '),
        row["SIZE"].PadRight(10, ' '),
        row["PRICE"].PadRight(10, ' ')));
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your solution. As far as I can see, there should be no problem with the code in the OP.

Comment: In my testing this didn't fix the issue as the problem is that the console is not using a fixed width font so just adding spaces will not align anything.

Comment: @juharr Not sure why your console isn't using a fixed width font - mine seems to default to that?

Comment: This is bad suggestion because width specifiers in format string as shown in OP's code do exactly that but without creating extra strings. Also code shown by the OP does exactly what they claim they want to achieve and this does not explain how code shown in the post ends up with output shown there (so far no one was able to reproduce the results).

Comment: @NetMage To be fair I was using LinqPad, but you can set the font used by the console to a font that isn't fixed width.  In the end using the OPs code or the code in this answer I got the exact same results that didn't line up until I copied and pasted them into NotePad++